# Why are my dates coming from the wrong dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

There is a dict with config for API requests.

Type of request and dates are indicated.

```
yt_params = {
    "yt_standard": {
        "startDate": "2019-08-01",
        "endDate": "2019-08-20",
    },

"yt_test": {
        "startDate": "2018-08-01",
        "endDate": "2018-08-20",
    }

}
```

For every type of request, metrics and dimensions are written in a database, so I put them in lists

requests_types list with pandas dfs with metadata for every request type, example

```
    request_type request_name     request_subtype
0   yt_standard  views,likes      metric
1   yt_standard  channel          dimension
```

I need to add them to the original dict and make a new one, or change yt_params like this

```
yt_params = {
    "yt_standard": {
        "ids": "channel==111",
        "startDate": "2019-08-01",
        "endDate": "2019-08-20",
        "metrics": "views,likes",
        "dimensions": "channel",
        "request_id": "1",
    }

"yt_test": {
        "ids": "channel==111",
        "startDate": "2018-08-01",
        "endDate": "2018-08-20",
        "metrics": "views,comments",
        "dimensions": "channel",
        "request_id": "2",
    }

}
```

So I ended up with this code so far:

```
#  initiate var for requests counting
j = 0
#  final dict
data_finish = {}

#  for every type
for request in requests_types :
    j = j + 1
    #  get the name of it
    re_type = request['request_type'][0]
    #  get metrics dimensions
    params = request['request_name'].to_list()

    #  iterate over dict 
    for k, v in yt_params.items():
        data =  {
        # constant
        "ids": "channel==111",    
        # get dates
        "startDate": v['startDate'],
        "endDate": v['endDate'],
        # get meta
        "metrics": params[0],
        "dimensions": params[1],
        # add number of request
        "request_id" : j
}
        # add data to dict
        data_finish['rt_' + request['request_type'][0]] = data
```

The result is

```
{'rt_yt_standard': {'ids': 'channel==111',
  'startDate': '2018-08-01',
  'endDate': '2018-08-20',
  'metrics': 'views,likes',
  'dimensions': 'channel',
  'request_id': 1},

 'rt_yt_test': {'ids': 'channel==111',
  'startDate': '2018-08-01',
  'endDate': '2018-08-20',
  'metrics': 'views,likes',
  'dimensions': 'channel',
  'request_id': 2}}
```

Everything is good but the dates are from the second request type. And this I can't get, while if I make such dict

```
dict_example = {}
j = 0

for k, v in yt_params.items():
    j = j + 1
    d = { 'sd': v['startDate'],
         'ed': v['endDate']}

    dict_example ['d' + str(j)] = d
```

It works ok:

```
{'d1': {'sd': '2019-08-01', 'ed': '2019-08-20'},
 'd2': {'sd': '2018-08-01', 'ed': '2018-08-20'}}
```

Comment: Please try to make your title less generic in the future. (I've edited this one for you; it's still not great, but it's a little more specific.)

Comment: Check your test string (I see a missing comma, is that a problem?), check your indentation (is `data_finish[...] = data` really inside the loop?)